# How to make karma.js crash on test fail?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, mocha.js, karma-runner

I am looking for a way to make karma.js crash when my tests fail so that my build process gets interrupted since that is easier to monitor in a remote building server.

I am using mocha as a reporter and jasmine as the test processor engine.

Is there any option or particular variable in the karma.conf.js file maybe that would allow me to "crash on test fail"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for a "crash on failure".

Your build process should check the exit code of the Karma process that it launches. If all test pass, the code will be 0. If there is a test failure, the code will be non-zero. (I've just checked and it was 1 when I tried.)

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to get a plugin for karma for your build server that will report the results of your tests.

For example, there's a plugin for karma/teamcity (karma-teamcity-reporter) which allows you to fail the build step, preventing the application from publishing if you have it set up that way.

Answer (score 0):

you can use grunt as automation tool to run your karma test case so that whenever any grunt job(test case) failed it will by default stop execution.